# Related Symbol Shortcut (Control-Command-Up Arrow) not working for Kotlin Activity class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

**What I am trying to achieve:** I want to use the ***Related Symbol Shortcut*** in a Kotlin based android activity class to navigate into its layout file.

**What is the issue:** While using the shortcut ***(Control-Command-Up Arrow)*** it shows me the tooltip error.

> “No related symbol”
>   [No related symbol tooltip error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHESk.png)
>   [Layout xml is linked correctly to kotlin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGRiP.png)

,  Whereas I am able to navigate from the layout file to the activity with no issue.

**What I have tried:**

- I have already checked for the `tools:context` attribute in the layout.xml it is correct. And Its also navigating me to the appropriate class using the same shortcut ***(Control-Command-Up Arrow)***.[Here is the proof of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udSJN.png)
- Just for the sake of solving this issue, I have created a sample java
  based activity and tried to achieve the same thing in it.
  **Surprisingly here everything is working fine.**